# Append data to DF with column names stored in list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Long time  listener, first time caller...

I'm new to python struggling to understand how to process lists for different purposes.  In this case, I have what will ultimately be a long list of float objects that I'd like to arrange into a dataframe, appending new rows with each loop.

```
cols = ['col1','col2'....etc...]
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)  

    for symbol in symbolList:

        col1 = some floating point calc
        col2 = another
        ...etc...

        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=[[','.join(cols)]]))
```

Even when I attempt different methods of manipulating the resulting string in an effort to persuade python to treat it as a list of objects rather than a string.

I'm sure there's not only a relatively simple way of modifying the data= argument so this runs, but an overall more pythonic way of achieving my end result.  I'd be happy to hear about the latter, but for my edification, if there is a solution to my specific question, I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `loc`

```
symbolList = [*'ABCDEFG']
for symbol in symbolList:
    col1 = np.random.randn()
    col2 = np.random.randn()

    df.loc[symbol] = [col1, col2]
```

However.  If you define your dataframe as `float` you can use `at`

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, dtype=float)  

symbolList = [*'ABCDEFG']
for symbol in symbolList:
    col1 = np.random.randn()
    col2 = np.random.randn()

    df.at[symbol] = [col1, col2]

df

       col1      col2
A -0.099437 -0.264494
B  0.460220 -0.250704
C -0.127054 -0.372424
D -0.909770  0.835610
E -0.442418  0.298014
F -0.468022  0.111015
G  0.080260  1.768664
```

Truth is, you could've used `at` to begin with but when you define your dataframe, the column's dtypes default to `object` and when you use `at` it does nothing to change it when you make new rows of `float`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  The note about defining the datatype as float is useful -- will definitely save that nugget for later.  What I'm really after here is a way to define my list of columns once (e.g., as you have in your cols list in the first line), then use that same list in line 9 (replacing the [col1, col2] from df.at[symbol] = [col1, col2] with a reference to the col list from line 1).  In past SAS-centric lives, I would have used a macro to resolve the variable list. Hope that's clearer.